# graphical relationship map for doctrine/mysql?

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine

i wonder if there is gui tools for creating a graphical map for the relationship between models/objects (doctrine) or tables (mysql)?

it would be better than draw it manually.

i´ve already have the models/objects and tables created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).  It has a screen for generating model diagrams from an SQL script or from a live database.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, I will add a recommendation of the [Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/architect) for the following reasons:

- platform and DB-independent, i.e. you get returns on your investment in learning how to use it with every database you use
- it can reverse engineer an existing DB
- it can manage differences between the model and the DB (generate scripts, update the DB directly etc.)
- the model editor is geared towards efficiency: sensible key bindings for important model elements, mostly flawless tab navigation...
- is FOSS

Answer (score 0):

For projects using Doctrine try our tool [Skipper - formerly ORM Designer](http://www.skipper18.com/) (I'm chief developer). It is designed for visual development with ORM frameworks. Therefore it supports all Doctrine properties, and you don't have to deal with the database level and SQL.

1. You can import, visualize and edit existing schemas,
2. or you can import data from MySQL Workbench,
3. or you can design ERD from scratch and generate schemas from it.